# Deprecation errors in mongoDB, where should I pass the parameters?

Tags: node.js, express, multer-gridfs-storage

I'm using mongoDB to store 2 files, and I get those messages:

***DeprecationWarning:*** current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

***DeprecationWarning:*** current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to 
the MongoClient constructor.

this is my code, I have no idea where should I pass those options to:

```
var storageImage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: dbURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: "user_images"
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});
const uploadImage = multer({ storage: storageImage });

var storageDoc = new GridFsStorage({
  url: dbURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: "user_cv"
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});
const uploadDoc = multer({ storage: storageDoc });

//routes

router.post("/uploadImage", uploadImage.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  res.json({ imageId: req.file.id });
});

router.post("/uploadCV", uploadDoc.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  res.json({ cvId: req.file.id });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Which module are you using to connect with mongodb?

Comment: @Dijkstra no module, I'm passing the mongoDB uri to the gridFS storage, and that's it

Comment: `new GridFsStorage` from where did you get it?

Comment: @Dijkstra const GridFsStorage = require("multer-gridfs-storage");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this. Adding this line should work `options: { useNewUrlParser: true }`.

```
new GridFsStorage({
  url: dbURI,
  options: { useNewUrlParser: true },
  ...,
});
```